# Concatenate data from a multidimensional Array and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array

I find that the code works as I intended (I think). But the last step in which I print the data feels wrong. The way I concatenate the html and js seems abit off. Is there a better way to concatenate this? Am I using the wrong solution to print the data?

// This list I use inside my Array.

```
    const myList = {
        Germany : {name : 'Germany', capital: 'Berlin', visited: 'Checked' },
        Italy : {name : 'Italy', capital: 'Rome', visited: 'Checked' },
        Spain : {name : 'Spain', capital: 'Madrid', visited: 'unchecked' },
    }
```

// My array

```
    const destinations = [];
```

// Push data from myList to destination-array.

```
    for(var key in myList) {
        destinations.push(myList[key]);
    }
```

// This is how write out my data on the page.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < destinations.length; i++) {
    document.write("<li><h1>" + destinations[i].name + "</h1><p>" + 
                   destinations[i].capital + 
                   "<input type='checkbox'" + destinations[i].visited + ">")
    };
```

This Is what I am planing to write out at the end.

```
<li class="all-destinations">
    <h3>destinations[i].name</h3>
    <div class="container">
        <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" destinations[i].visited>
        </label>
    </div>
    <p>destinations[i].capital</p>
    <hr>
</li>
```

Comment: Instead of looping through keys of `myList` you can simply do: `const destinations = Object.values(myList)`

Comment: You can make this better by moving the concatenation logic to a separate function which returns the html only. That way, it would work like a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the values to the innerHTML property directly without `document.write` which may not work if the page is already full loaded.

```js
function getItems({ name, capital, visited }) {
    return `<li class="all-destinations">
        <h3>${name}</h3>
        <div class="container">
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" ${visited}>
            </label>
        </div>
        <p>${capital}</p>
        <hr>
    </li>`;
}


const myList = { Germany: { name: 'Germany', capital: 'Berlin', visited: 'Checked' }, Italy: { name: 'Italy', capital: 'Rome', visited: 'Checked' }, Spain: { name: 'Spain', capital: 'Madrid', visited: 'unchecked' } };

document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += Object.values(myList).map(getItems).join('');
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You made your code better in three ways:

- Use `Object.values()` instead of creating `[]` and pushing to it.
- You can use `forEach()` rather than simple for loops
- You should use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create html string.

```js
const myList = {
        Germany : {name : 'Germany', capital: 'Berlin', visited: 'Checked' },
        Italy : {name : 'Italy', capital: 'Rome', visited: 'Checked' },
        Spain : {name : 'Spain', capital: 'Madrid', visited: 'unchecked' },
    }
    
const list = Object.values(myList);

list.forEach(x => {
  document.write(
  `<li class="all-destinations">
      <h3>${x.name}</h3>
      <div class="container">
        <label class="switch">
          <input type="checkbox" ${x.visited}>
        </label>
      </div>
      <p>${x.capital}</p>
      <hr>
  </li>`)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the great input! I learned a lot from your answer, but I still chose to accept @Nina Scholz's answer as the correct one.